# write a C# code for extracting a .csv file, if i give one of the element of first column, i get the corresponding values of the other two columns

Tags: c#

this is my .csv file:

```
Apple,rose,tiger
Mango,lily,cheetah
Banana,sunflower,lion
Apple,marigold,cat
```

input: `Mango` (i write it in the text box)
desired output:

```
 Flower = lily;  Animal = cheetah
```

similarly,

input: `Apple`
desired output:

```
Flower = rose,marigold;  Animal = tiger,cat
```

this is the code i have written:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\asp_net\abc.csv"))
        {
            List<string> listA = new List<string>();
            List<string> listB = new List<string>();
            List<string> listC = new List<string>();
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                var line = reader.ReadLine();
                var values = line.Split(',');
                listA.Add(values[0]);
                listB.Add(values[1]);
                listC.Add(values[2]);
            }

            string checkThis = obj.SearchSenSig(textBox1.Text);

            if (listA.Any(checkThis.Contains))
            {

                int count = listA.Where(x => x.Equals(checkThis)).Count();

                if (count == 1)
                {
                    int index = listA.IndexOf(checkThis);
                    var firstItem = listB.ElementAt(index);
                    var secondItem = listC.ElementAt(index);
                    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("receiver = {0}, url = {1}", firstItem, secondItem));
                }

                else
                {
                    foreach (string item in listA)
                    {
                        int i = listA.IndexOf(item);

                        bool result = item.Equals(checkThis);
                        if (result)
                        {

                            List<string> myCollection1 = new List<string>();
                            myCollection1.Add(listB.ElementAt(i));

                            string firstItem = string.Join(",", myCollection1);
                            List<string> myCollection2 = new List<string>();
                            myCollection2.Add(listC.ElementAt(i));

                            string secondItem = string.Join(",", myCollection2);
                            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Flower = {0}, Animal = {1}", firstItem, secondItem));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The search element does not exists.");
            }
        }
```

Still i am not getting the desired output. Please help.

Comment: What exactly do you get? Do you know how to debug your code (Set a breakpoint and step through your file)?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a different list for each column, create a single class to hold an entire row data:

```
class Data // I'll bet you can find a better name for this class...
{
    public string Fruit {get;set;}
    public string Flower {get;set;}
    public string Animal {get;set;}
}
```

and populate a list of this class:

```
private List<Data> data = new List<Data>(); // note: this is a field, not a local variable.
```

Populating this list should be done only once, in the constructor or in the `form_load` event:

```
while (!reader.EndOfStream)
{
    var line = reader.ReadLine();
    var values = line.Split(',');
    data.Add(
        new Data() 
        { 
            Fruit = values[0],
            Flower = values[1],
            Animal = values[2]
        }
    );
}
```

Now all you have to do in the `button_click` event handler is get all the items corresponding to your search string. Assuming you are only searching for fruits using the [`FindAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.findall?view=netframework-4.7.2) method and display the results:

```
var result = data.FindAll(d => d.Fruit == searchString);
```

This will return a list of `Data` where the `Fruit` property contains the same string as `searchString`. use linq and string.Join to format the results into a string:

```
var resultString = $"Flower = {string.Join(",", result.Select(r => r.Flower))}; Animal = {string.Join(",", result.Select(r => r.Animal))}";
```

Comment: private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            obj = new WebService1SoapClient(); //error: '} expected'
            private List<MyData> data = new List<MyData>();
        }   
    }
} //at the end of my code i am getting the error 'Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected'

Comment: It's very hard to understand the code you've posted in the comment, especially with the added comments. Please paste the code into a 3rd party website such as rextester or .net fiddle and comment with a link to it.